# SimpleDateFormat parse JDK 11 & 12 vs JDK 14

Tags: java

I have a test that used to work in JDK 11 and JDK 12:

```
@Test
public void billingDateFormat() throws Exception {

    final SimpleDateFormat billingDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    final LocalDate x = DateTimeUtils.javaUtilDateToLocalDate(billingDateFormatter.parse("Dec 1, 2014"));
    assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 1), x);
}
```

However, when I upgraded to JDK 14 it says it cannot parse `Dec 1, 2014`

Is that test no longer valid or is it a bug on JDK 14?

Works with

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu12.3+11-CA (build 12.0.2+3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu12.3+11-CA (build 12.0.2+3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It fails on

```
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   DateTimeUtilsTest.billingDateFormat:26 » Parse Unparseable date: "Dec 1, 2014"
```

Locale is `en_CA` for both JDK 12 and JDK 14

Comment: Java 11 or 14 and `java.util.SimpleDateFormat`? Why? Why not `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: You really should drop the old API because you have access to [`java.time`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) in JDK 14.

Comment: You are using *terrible* date-time classes that are now obsolete legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Keep `LocalDate`, but stop using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: What error /exception do you get? I would expect it to run in JDK14 - no errors when I run `new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy").parse("Dec 1, 2014")`

Comment: Which is the default locale of your Java 12 JVM? And of your Java 14 JVM? If you don’t know, use `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

- The exception your mention but do not document is likely due to relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default `Locale`.
- Your JVM’s current default time zone varies at runtime, possibly throwing off your expected date by a day.

  - Run `billingDateFormatter.getTimeZone()` to see the zone in play.
  - Look at [code in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DKQupo) as proof.
- You are using terrible date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes as shown in [Answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535403/642706).
- Tip: Do not exchange date-time values textually in localized formats. Use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## Specify a `Locale` when parsing

I have tried running your parsing code in Java 14.0.1 on my own machine. And I [ran it on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DKQupo) under Java 12.0.1. Both succeed.

So I suspect your problem is related to `Locale`, as [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535189/simpledateformat-parse-jdk-11-12-vs-jdk-14/62541991#comment110600234_62535189). Your input string contains the name of the month in English, and abbreviated in a certain way. To correctly translate the name of the month, you must specify a human language. To correctly interpret the abbreviation, you must specify a set of cultural norms. Both the language and norms are contained in a `Locale` object.

Your code does not specify a `Locale`. So the JVM’s current default locale will be applied implicitly. At runtime, that default may vary. If your development machine has a JVM defaulting to `Locale.US`, your code runs successfully. If at runtime the deployment machine has a JVM defaulting to `Locale.JAPAN`, then your code fails, unable to translate `Dec` to the first month of the year.

To see the JVM’s current default locale, run:

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

But keep in mind that the default can change at *any* moment. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can change the default to another `Locale` object. Doing so immediately affects all other code in all apps in all threads. So I suggest you never rely on the default. Specify the desired/expected locale explicitly.

The direct solution is to specify a locale on your `SimpleDateFormat` object.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Or Locale.UK, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, and so on.
final SimpleDateFormat billingDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM d, yyyy" , locale );  // Pass a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to be used in translation.
```

But the larger solution is to never use `SimpleDateFormat`.

And, you have another problem: time zone.

## Date varies by time zone

Understand that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. At any moment, it may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while still “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

## `SimpleDateFormat.parse` applies an assigned time zone

Your use of obsolete legacy class `SimpleDateFormat`, along with its implicit use of the JVM’s current default time zone, could produce results that vary at runtime.

You are parsing a string that represents a date only, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone. Yet the [`DateFormat::parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method you call returns a `java.util.Date` object. The `Date` class is misnamed, and represents a moment, a point on the timeline in UTC. In other words, a `Date` is a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. So, square peg, round hole.

In a poorly advised attempt to smash that square peg to fit, the `SimpleDateFormat` class is applying a default time zone by which to determine a first moment of the day on that date in that zone.

Your code ignores this crucial issue of time zone. Yet a time zone is still in play. But the time zone is being applied implicitly, behind the scenes.

To show this, let's run code similar to yours. We will specify explicitly a time zone of UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

Dump the version of Java, as you believed this to be version related issue.

```
System.out.println( Runtime.version() );
```

Define your desired formatter. We are using `SimpleDateFormat` here because you insist, but in real work I would *never* use this class. The [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class is its modern replacement.

```
SimpleDateFormat billingDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM d, yyyy" );
```

We will set a time zone explicitly. I suspect this is the cause of your issue: You are implicitly assigning the JVM’s current default time zone rather than assigning one. That default varies at runtime, so you see differing behaviors.

```
billingDateFormatter.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Etc/UTC" ) );
```

Verify the assignment of that time zone. One of the many design flaws in the legacy date-time cases is that `TimeZone.getTimeZone` fails silently when you pass a zone name it does not recognize. So you must double-check. Again, I would *never* use this class in real work, instead using its replacements `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`.

```
System.out.println( billingDateFormatter.getTimeZone() );  // Verify the time zone.
```

Parse your input string. We catch an exception thrown if input is invalid.

```
java.util.Date d = null;
try
{
    d = billingDateFormatter.parse( "Dec 1, 2014" );
}
catch ( ParseException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Convert the `java.util.Date` object to its modern replacement, `Instant`. Both classes represent a moment in UTC. From there we assign an offset to get a more flexible `OffsetDateTime` object that represents a moment in any offset-from-UTC. From there we extract just the date portion as a `LocalDate`, ignoring the time-of-day portion and the offset portion.

```
LocalDate ld = d.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate();
```

We specify our expected date result.

```
LocalDate expected = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.DECEMBER , 1 );
```

We compare the two `LocalDate` objects to see if our expectation were met.

```
boolean metExpectations = ld.equals( expected );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "d = " + d );
System.out.println( "ld = " + ld );
System.out.println( "expected = " + expected );
System.out.println( "metExpectations = " + metExpectations );
```

When run. Here we see results in Java 14. See the same [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DKQupo) in Java 12.

> 14.0.1+7

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

> d = Sun Nov 30 16:00:00 PST 2014

> ld = 2014-12-01

> expected = 2014-12-01

> metExpectations = true

But now let's change that assigned time zone to one in the far East, far ahead of UTC. Instead of `"Etc/UTC"` as name of the time zone, we use `"Asia/Tokyo"`. Notice how the resulting date is November 30 rather than December 1. Also notice how the `java.util.Date` object represents a different moment than seen above.

```
billingDateFormatter.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Asia/Tokyo" ) );
```

Results:

> 14.0.1+7

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Tokyo",offset=32400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=10,lastRule=null]

> d = Sun Nov 30 07:00:00 PST 2014

> ld = 2014-11-30

> expected = 2014-12-01

> metExpectations = false

## Conclusion

- Your JVM’s current default locale is not expecting the English `Dec` abbreviated name for the last month of the year.
- Your JVM’s current default time zone varies at runtime, giving you a date that is a day off from what you might expect.

Sadly, all of this was a waste of time, as your Question is moot. You should never be using any of the legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar`. Use only date-time classes from the *java.time* package names. The *java.time* framework is industry-leading, and is brilliantly designed by people who understand the intricacies of date-time handling, led by [Stephen Colebourne](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephencolebourne/).

To see the modern solution, look at the [Answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535403/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), which is able to take a specific [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) in order to parse month names given in a specific language, which may be a or the reason for unparseable date(time)s.

You are using [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), so you should use the formatting option of that package, too.

Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in translating the month name `Dec`.

```
@Test
public void billingDateFormat() throws Exception {
    final DateTimeFormatter billingDateFormatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MMM d, yyyy",
            Locale.ENGLISH
        );
    final LocalDate x = LocalDate.parse("Dec 1, 2014", billingDateFormatter);
    assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 1), x);
}
```

Comment: doesn't answer my question

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Actually, this Answer does address the larger problem: your use of terrible legacy classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community [gave up on those classes](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=5639) years ago. And so should you. For details of the issues in your code, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541991/642706). Or save yourself the grief and the time by just adopting the code shown here.